# <strong></strong> does not work inside table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem with `strong` tags inside of tables not being bolded. I have the following html code:

Here I have a fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/JxQCr/

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="row_table">
            <td>2012</td>
            <td><strong>this should be strong</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2012</td>
            <td>not strong</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>not strong</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using JSFiddle's [`normalize.css`](http://jsfiddle.net/css/normalize.css) option which adds a *load* of CSS overrides.

[Turn it off](http://jsfiddle.net/JxQCr/2/) and everything's fine

There are other normalisers which have better defaults for `strong` tags - e.g. http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/ - but this only proves how important it is to understand the code you're including in your project

Comment: lol normalizing stuff is not always a good choice ;-) THanx a lot!

Comment: Actually note that JSFiddle's normalise.css isn't the same as the normalise.css project I linked to. The one I linked to has a much more sensible rule for `strong` - it makes it bold

Comment: in my project its the same...which normalizer do you link?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using some kind of reset css? if so try setting the font-weight for  manually

```
strong{
  font-weight: bold;
}​
```

or

```
table td strong{
  font-weight: bold;
}​
```

Answer (score -1):

Uncheck "Normalized CSS" option in JSFiddle. Re-Run the code, it will work.

Tool overrides lot of stuffs.